# How to perform an action in Wordpress only once - add_user_meta()

Tags: wordpress, plugins

As per the question, my intent is to perform an action only and only once, this is because the behavior of the code that I will write, leads to record new records, every time Wordpress is loaded, how can I overcome this?

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'test' );
function test()
{
    add_user_meta(100, 'favorite_books', 'WordPress Dev Champ', false);
    add_user_meta(100, 'favorite_books', 'WordPress Lazy Coder', false);
    add_user_meta(100, 'favorite_books', 'WordPress The Hard Way', false);
}
```

So in conclusion, my goal is to have `meta_value` different for the same `meta key only and only 3 times`

Comment: Can you explain it?

Comment: @GufranHasan in what sense can you explain it? is already explained, by executing this code in the form of a plugin, every time you reload the browser will always add 3 records, I have to use this code, but make sure that the records are recorded only once and that's it

Comment: for the same ID it will overwrite the values. Is there any specific event or reason do you want to save these data.

Comment: @GufranHasan no, not at all, it always adds the same values ​​as new records n times every n page loads

Comment: you need to put a condition `if(empty(get_usermeta(100, 'favorite_books')))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this condition. This is not tested but hope will work for you.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'test' );
function test()
{
if(empty(get_user_meta( 100, 'favorite_books', true ))){
    add_user_meta(100, 'favorite_books', 'WordPress Dev Champ', false);
    add_user_meta(100, 'favorite_books', 'WordPress Lazy Coder', false);
    add_user_meta(100, 'favorite_books', 'WordPress The Hard Way', false);

 }
}
```